# React setState don't update the UI or triggers useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

So I'have a initial state in my wrapper component with two items

```
 const initialData = {
    first: clubData.applications[0].invoice_url,
    second: clubData.applications[0].invoice_url_2,
  };

  const [invoiceFiles, setInvoiceFiles] = useState(initialData);
```

, the component has 2 childs and each child gets one of the items as file prop and also functions to change the state accroding to which property from state they use.

```
  <AddInvoice
          admin={admin}
          clubData={clubData}
          addFile={(file) => addFile("first", file)}
          file={invoiceFiles.first}
          deleteFile={() => deleteFile("first")}
          invoiceUrl={clubData.applications[0].invoice_url}
        />
```

when i invoke the addFile function from AddInvoice component nothing happens in wrapper components, not even the useEffect function is called.Anyone know's why it is happening?

Here's my full wrapper code:

```
const AddInvoiceWrapper = ({ clubData, admin }) => {
  const initialData = {
    first: clubData.applications[0].invoice_url,
    second: clubData.applications[0].invoice_url_2,
  };

  const [invoiceFiles, setInvoiceFiles] = useState(initialData);

  const addFile = (index, file) => {
    let newFiles = invoiceFiles;
    newFiles[index] = file;
    console.log(newFiles);
    setInvoiceFiles(newFiles);
  };

  const deleteFile = (index) => {
    let newFiles = invoiceFiles;
    newFiles[index] = null;
    setInvoiceFiles(newFiles);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("invoice files changed!");
  }, [invoiceFiles]);

  return (
    <Row>
      <Column>
        <Paragraph>Dodaj fakturę (dev) </Paragraph>
        <AddInvoice
          admin={admin}
          clubData={clubData}
          addFile={(file) => addFile("first", file)}
          file={invoiceFiles.first}
          deleteFile={() => deleteFile("first")}
          invoiceUrl={clubData.applications[0].invoice_url}
        />
      </Column>
      {invoiceFiles.first != null ? (
        <Column>
          <Paragraph>Dodaj koretkę faktury</Paragraph>
          <AddInvoice
            admin={admin}
            clubData={clubData}
            addFile={(file) => addFile("second", file)}
            file={invoiceFiles.second}
            deleteFile={() => deleteFile("second")}
            invoiceUrl={clubData.applications[0].invoice_url_2}
          />
        </Column>
      ) : null}
    </Row>
  );
};

export default AddInvoiceWrapper;
```

And this is also function in child components that triggers function in wrapper:

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };
```

The data is passed with no problems and in addFile function i get the proper new object but when i use "setInvoiceFiles" nothing happens, i see the change only when i make some changes in the code and the hot reload automaticily runs and refreshes the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `newFiles` like this: `let newFiles = invoiceFiles;`
`newFiles` will have the same reference as `invoiceFiles`. When React compare object, it compares their references, since your `newFiles` and `invoiceFiles` have same reference (even though inner values are different), React won't mark it as an update so it won't trigger re-render or call useEffect

The solution is simple: Just change the line I mentioned to this:

```
let newFiles = {...invoiceFiles};
```

This time, newFiles will be a totally new variable with different reference.

Answer (score 2):

Because the pointers are the same, React will not consider this a new data, and will not re-render. try  `setInvoiceFiles([...newFiles]);` instead.

you can read about spread operator (...) here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

You need to return new array to update state:

```
const addFile = (index, file) => {
  setInvoiceFiles((preState) =>
    preState.map((item, i) => {
      return index === i ? file : item;
    }),
  );
};
```